# what is twitter-bootstrap mixin naming convention

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In twitter-bootstrap mixin: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins.less

There are mixins naming by dash and camelCase:
.buttonBackground
.input-block-level

In 3.0.0-wip branch
We also have underscore:
clear_float

My question is what is mixin naming convention?Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap uses less by default . You are getting confused with Variables and Mixins(can be understood as functions)

So camels are used with variables like :

```
@color: #333;

  #nav {
   color: @color;
  }
```

@color is a variable here .

Now mixins allow us to add all the properties of a class into another class by simply referencing its class name in it . For example :

```
.center-block() {
    display: block;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
   }
```

We can use the class `center-block` above directly into a new class which we want to have same property . i.e :

```
#nav > li > a{
       .center-block;
```

}

The mixins are simple classes declared and which can be used anywhere . So the naming convention for them is a regular way in which we declared other classes in css .

But if you just want to differentiate between mixins and other classes .. you can have a specific way of writing them ... Like first alphabet as capital .. you know just something which is useful for you .

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So, there is no such 'best practice' thing in twitter bootstrap mixin naming? For example, in ruby we write all the method using underscore: this_is_a_method; write class using camelCase: ThisIsAClass.

Comment: See bootstrap is a framework , its not a language . So it uses the convention provided by css and if you dive into less . The conventions are basically theirs . So the best practice to write a good code in css implies to bootstrap as well . And in css dashes are widely used to create classes like , round-corners , clear-float . Underscores are not used . In less @ is for variables and mixins are classes , so you can declare them like regular css classes or create a simple differentiation method of ur own .

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. But why bootstrap guy did not stick to one convention: dash for mixin?

Comment: where did ya find dash .. ? And if its there.. they would have wanted to keep note of that mixin to not get mixed with something similar they might have